# Как показать блок при прокрутке страницы вверх?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть вопроса сделать визуальное оформление под загрузки нового контента.
Как например на яндекс почте в мобильной версии, если прокрутишь страницу вверх выезжает из-под `header` gif картинка(preloader) и через секунду исчезает.

```
<div id="header">
  menu
</div>
<div class="ploader">
  Загрузка
</div>
```

Главное чтобы картинка не показывалась при загрузке новой страницы, а только если прокручиваешь страницу немного вниз и в самый верх.

Нужно добавить класс `animateClass` к классу `ploader` при прокрутке **в самый** верх?

Вот пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/GobYNK

В примере добавляется класс при прокрутке с любого положения, а нужно только когда прокрутил к самому началу страницы?

Comment: http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/VeJNBd

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема, вначале через css скрыть его ,а через [.scroll()](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) получить значение при прокрутки и когда нужно показать?
Например как сделать что бы элемент отображался только вверху:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop === 0) $('.ploader').addClass('animateClass');
    else $('.ploader').removeClass('animateClass');
});
```

Comment: нужно не только показать но и скрыть, пример не понятный.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин изменил

Comment: @СергейЛапшин , а вы не видите её? Я специально оставил что бы вы добавили свои проверки "&& ...", убрал.

Comment: Нужно добавить класс animateClass к классу ploader при прокрутке вверх, а не вниз как у вас.

Comment: Так и есть: https://jsfiddle.net/iliailia1212/L2d8y59k/2/

Comment: Вот пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/GobYNK работает как надо только чтобы добавлялся класс в самом верху страницы и исчезал через 2 секунды, а не как сейчас с любого положения.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин вот так что ли? https://jsfiddle.net/iliailia1212/L2d8y59k/3/

Comment: Не так! Написал же. Нужно когда крутишь вниз ничего не происходило. А когда докрутишь в самый верх до нулевой точки добавлялся класс на несколько секунд.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, а сейчас по вашему как? И в чём проблема сделать самому, когда есть пример и понимание что нужно?

Comment: А вы разницу не видите? У вас и вниз и вверх с любой точки класс добавляется, а надо только вверх и не везде, а только когда страница подходит в самый верх. Я уже 5 раз об этом писал.